# How can I instantiate a class with a method (if possible) in c#?

Tags: c#, class, oop, instance

Say you had some sort of console-application game, and inside the game you create an object which would have it's own class. How would you make an instance of that class with something like a method or function while the game might still be running.

I've looked all over the internet and haven't found anything after weeks. Normally, I would just create an array for the class and add new instances to it like so.

```
class MyClass 
{
   //fields and methods
}

class Program 
{
   static void Main(string[] args) 
   {
      MyClass[] myClasses = new MyClass[16];
      myClasses.SetValue(new MyClass(), 0);
   }
}
```

But this feels clunky and inefficient. I hope I figure this out soon.

Comment: It's unclear what your aim is and what the array is for, but without context, this code looks fine except normally you'd set the value at an array index with `myClasses[i] = new MyClass()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The most common and accepted way may be the `FactoryPattern`.

Create your factory:

```
public static class MyClassFactory
{

    public static MyClass CreateNew() {
        return new MyClass();
    }
    
    public static MyClass[] CreateRange(int amount) {
        
        var myArr = new MyClass[amount];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            myArr[i] = new MyClass();
        }
        
        return myArr;
    }
}
```

Then simply call it in your code:

```
class Program 
{
   static void Main(string[] args) 
   {
      MyClass[] myClasses = MyClassFactory.CreateRange(16);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this:

```
  var myClasses = new MyClass[16];
  myClasses[0] = new MyClass();
```